# cmp-command for three files

Tags: bash, shell, file-comparison

I'd like to compare three text files using the cmp-command in bash and perform an action, if file1 differs from file2, but file1 and file3 are exactly the same. As according to the help-file, cmp outputs a 0 if the files are the same and a 1 if they differ, I tried:

```
if [ "cmp -s file1.txt file2.txt" != 0 ] && [ "cmp -s file1.txt file3.txt" == 0 ]; then
#Action
else
#Do nothing
fi
```

However, the partial condition
`if [ "cmp -s file1.txt file2.txt" != 0 ]` does not even work as a single if-condition, nor does the second, because they act the same way if the two files are the same or not.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the literal text `cmp -s file1.txt file2.txt` to the string `0`, which will never match. Use this instead,

```
if ! cmp -s file1.txt file2.txt && cmp -s file1.txt file3.txt
then
    #Action
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, trying it out soon. I also tried `if [ $(cmp -s file1.txt file2.txt) != 0 ]`, why won‘t that condition work?

Comment: @X3nion `cmp -s` does not output anything. Do you know what "exit-status" is? `cmp -s` exits with a 0 or 1 exit-status depending on whether the files are the same or different.  This is used by the `if` statement.  The 0 or 1 is never actually outputted, so it can't be captured by a command substitution.

Comment: @X3nion try `echo "Output x$(cmp -s file1.txt file2.txt)x"`. You'll see you get `Output xx`, demonstrating that `cmp -s` doesn't output anything to _stdout_.